# Yii why should I use registerCssFile() and registerScriptFile()?

Tags: php, yii

What is the difference between using  registerCssFile() and  `<link rel="stylesheet" ... >`  ?

What has YIi Framework done while I used registerCssFile() for improving the web site's performance ?

Is there any benefit to SEO when I using registerCssFile() ?

Comment: if you go with yiis way, you can unregister scripts, anywhere you want, you have control over it

Answer (score 2):

The use of `registerCssFile()` will give you some advanced possibilities:

- **css post-processing** - for example you can combine all registered css files to one and minimize them (see Yii extension [EClientScript](https://github.com/muayyad-alsadi/yii-EClientScript)). Such post-processing will improve the loading time of your web site.
- **control** - you can use framework functions to include / exclude css files.
- **API for modules/extensions** - with `registerCssFile()` extensions and modules do have the possibility to include/render css files within your main layout (your website HTML).

The mentioned points are also valid for js files registered with `registerScriptFile()`.

I can't think of any SEO benefits when using this Yii feature though.